# Записание в TextBox несколько раз подряд

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Возникла проблема, пишу программу на WPF и мне нужно заполнять `TextBox`
Дело в том, что я заполняю `TextBox` последовательно после проверки разных условий

Например:

```
if (a == 1)
{
    Output.Text = "a";
}

if (b == 2)
{
    Output.Text = "b";
}
```

Проблема в том, что при таком оформлении программа выводит в `TextBox` последнюю команду, которая удовлетворила условиям

Например:

```
Вход:

a = 1

b = 2

Программа выведет:

b
```

Мне же нужно, чтобы программа не стирала прошлое значение из `TextBox` - какую функцию применить?

Comment: `+=` а не `=` (2 символа)

Comment: Помогло, запишите это в ответ!

Comment: Позволю сделать это вам, удачи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось гениально простым - спасибо @EvgeniyZ !
При добавление текста:

```
Output.Text = "b";
```

Нужно просто написать не `"="`, a `"+="`:

```
Output.Text += "b";
```